# Counting the number of holes in a number

Tags: java

I'm trying to figure out how to count the number of "holes" in a number. That is, where 8 has two holes. 0, 4, 6, 9 have one hole and the rest have none using the Switch statement.

For some reason, I am getting 3 instead of 5 when I test it using this number 6457819. Please any ideas on how I can improve my solution? I want to use a switch case for my solution.

```
public class HolePractice {
 static int value[] = {1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 2, 1};   
 static int countHoles(int num) {
      int holes = 0;
      
      String numHole = Integer.toString(num);
      switch(numHole) {
      case "1":
      case "2":
      case "3":
      case "5":
      case "7":
          return 0;
      case "0":
      case "4":
      case "6":
      case "9":
          return 1;
      case "8":
          return 2;
      }
     
      for(int i=0; i <= numHole.length(); i++)
      holes = holes + value[i];
    return holes;
        
  }
```

Comment: Please share your exact code, what you shared doesn't even compile ;)

Comment: The inside of your loop never uses `numHole` for anything at all. That should be a red flag that something may have been forgotten.

Comment: Note that you have _two separate representations_ of "number of holes per digit" in your code. This is also a warning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are adding `values` instead of the `numHole` in your loop. It looks like you wanted to recurse for each digit. That would look something like,

```
static int countHoles(int num) {
    int holes = 0;

    String numHole = Integer.toString(num);
    switch (numHole) {
    case "1":
    case "2":
    case "3":
    case "5":
    case "7":
        return 0;
    case "0":
    case "4":
    case "6":
    case "9":
        return 1;
    case "8":
        return 2;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < numHole.length(); i++) {
        holes += countHoles(numHole.charAt(i) - '0');
    }
    return holes;
}
```

But we could also break it down a little further. First a method to count the holes in a single digit. You can use a `switch` case but fall out for the unmatched cases to return `0` (the base case). Like,

```
static int countDigitHole(int v) {
    switch (v) {
    case 0:
    case 4:
    case 6:
    case 9:
        return 1;
    case 8:
        return 2;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Then invoke that by considering each digit in `num` as the remainder of division by 10 (modulo 10). Like

```
static int countHoles(int num) {
    int holes = 0;
    while(num > 0) {
        holes += countDigitHole(num % 10);
        num /= 10;
    }
    return holes;
}
```

No `String`(s) required.

Comment: Frisch Your solution worked. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can store the values in a `Map` as a reference, check if `num` is in that `Map` and return the relevant value.

```java
Map<Integer, Integer> numbers = new HashMap<>();
numbers.put(0, 1);
numbers.put(4, 1);
numbers.put(6, 1);
numbers.put(8, 2);
numbers.put(9, 1);

int holePractice(int num) {
    if (numbers.containsKey(num)) {
        return numbers.get(num);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, there's no need to repeatedly call the method for every digit. You just need to iterate over the switch clause, switching on each String digit.  The `split` splits the string between digits yielding an array of `String digits`.

```
 for (String digit : Integer.toString(num).split("")) {
      switch(digit) {
```

You don't need to return the values for each switch case.  Just add them to the hole count in each case and return the hole count when done.

```
case "6":
case "9":
    holes++;
    break;
...
... 
}
return holes;
}
```

And here is an example of using numeric digits combined with the enhanced switch capability introduced in Java 14.

- This switches on the the last digit using the `remainder` operator
- it ignores digits without holes using `default` value of 0.
- division by 10 prepares `num` for the next digit

```
static int countHoles(int num) {
    int holes = 0;
    while (num > 0) {
        holes += switch (num % 10) {
            case 0, 4, 6, 9 -> 1;
            case 8 -> 2;
            default -> 0;
        };
        num /= 10;
    }
    return holes;
}
```